# Split a comma separated string but only split by a comma

Tags: php, regex, string, split, substring

Hi I have a long string

```
0BV,0BW,100,102,108,112,146,163191,192,193,1D94,19339,1A1,1AA,1AE,1AFD,1AG,1AKF.......
```

I want to show it in a page by sub sting them

like

```
0BV,0BW,100,102,108,112,146
163191,192,193,1D94,19339
1A1,1AA,1AE,1AFD,1AG,1AKF
```

What i want to do is create sub strings from the string , length of 100 characters , but if the 100 th character is a not a comma i want to check the next comma in the string and split by that .

I tried to use `chunk()` to split by word count , but since the sub-string lengths are different , it is showing inappropriate in the page

```
$db_ocode   = $row["option_code"];

$exclude_options_array =    explode(",",$row["option_code"]);
$exclude_options_chunk_array = array_chunk($exclude_options_array,25);

$exclude_options_string = '';   
foreach($exclude_options_chunk_array as $exclude_options_chunk)
{
    $exclude_options_string .= implode(",",$exclude_options_chunk);
    $exclude_options_string .= "</br>";
}
```

Please help . thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the string, set the cutoff position. If that position does not contain a comma then find the first comma after that position and cut off there. Simple

```
<?php

$string="0BV,0BW,100,102,108,112,146,163191,192,193,1D94,19339,1A1,1AA,1AE,1AFD";

$cutoff=30;
if($string[$cutoff]!=",")
  $cutoff=strpos($string,",",$cutoff);
echo substr($string,0,$cutoff);
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/240687)**

Answer (score 2):

```
(.{99})(?=,),|([^,]*),
```

Instead of split you can grab the captures which is much easy.See demo for `20` characters.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/37

Comment: Nice answer :). Is that 99 a typo cause fiddle is for 19. Oops sorry its not, because that 99 is what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky no OP wants for `100` characters.The `100th` character is that `,` after `.{99}`

Answer (score 1):

Using Hanky Panky's answer i was able to provide a complete solution to my Problem  , Thank you very much Hanky panky . If my code is not efficient ,Kindly please edit it .

```
$string="0BV,0BW,100,102,108,112,146,163191,192,193,1D94,19339,1A1,1AA,1AE,1AFD";

for($start=0;$start<strlen($string);) {

       $cutoff=30;
       if(isset($string[$start+$cutoff]) && $string[$start+$cutoff]!=",") 
       {
          $cutoff=strpos($string,",",$start+$cutoff);        
       }
       else if(($start+$cutoff) >= strlen($string))
       {
          $cutoff = strlen($string);
       }
       else if($start >= 30)
       {
          $cutoff = $start + $cutoff;
       }

       echo substr($string,$start,$cutoff-$start)."\n";
       $start=$cutoff+1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case python

```
ln=0
i=1
str='0BVAa,0BW,100,102,108,112,146,163191,192,193,1D94,19339,1A1,1AA,1AE,1AFD,1AG,1AKF'
for item in str:
    print (item),
    ln=ln+len(item)
    if ln/10>=i and item==',':
        print ""
        i=i+1
```